# Strange MIPS address behaviour

Tags: mips

im a newbie in MIPS and still scratching some basic commands, currently i bumped into a very strange situation, where i have 2 identical code but one runs, and the other doesnt.

This is the code that throw an exception when running at line `sw $v0, input`:

```
.data

Text_output1: .asciiz "Input number 1: "
input: .word

.text
main:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, Text_output1
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall

sw $v0, input
li $v0, 1
lw $a0, input
add $a0, $a0, 1
syscall
```

This is the normal functioning one:

```
# Program: Hello, World!
.data

# data declaration section; specifies values to be stored
# in memory and labels whereby the values are accessed

Greeting: .asciiz "\nghfhgfhgf\n"
Text_output1: .asciiz "Number 1 : "
input: .word

.text # Start of code section
main: # Execution begins at label "main"
li $v0, 4 #in ra number 1 :
la $a0, Text_output1
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall

sw $v0, input
li $v0, 1
lw $a0, input
add $a0, $a0, 1
syscall
```

I cannot see any difference between the twos, or is there something i dont know about this language?

Btw im using MARS 4.5 with JDK 13. Thank you so much.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: it said `Runtime exception at 0x0040001c: store address not aligned on word boundary 0x10010011`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're writing any MIPS assembly, you should get the official instruction set reference (*MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers
Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set*).

For the `sw` instruction it states the following:

> **Restrictions:**
>   The effective address must be naturally-aligned. If either of the 2 least-significant bits of the address is non-zero, an
>   Address Error exception occurs.

As the simulator clearly states, you have an `sw` instruction at address `0x0040001c` that tries to write to address `0x10010011`, which is not a word-aligned address.

Your second example happens to work out of pure luck, because your two strings occupy 24 bytes of memory, so the `input` label ends up 24 bytes from the start of the `.data` section, which is a word-aligned address.

To ensure proper alignment, use the `.align` directive, e.g.:

```
.align 2
input: .word 0
```

Also note the `0` after `.word`. If you leave out the initial value and just write `.word` you will run into problems if you add more variables (they will all get the same address).